# How to use a var to break from all recursive calls?

Tags: python, recursion

So i am writing a recursive function that find best score of 2 dna strands, my problem is that i have 2 vars i wanna save and use(vars outside of the function, like filed vars on java):

1) if best solution found, i dont wanna keep searching
2) and keep a var that contains the best solution i have so far, so if the current score cant top it no matter what, i wanna stop searching.

code:

```
def main_fun(str1,str2)
    best_so_far = None
    best_score_possible = len(str)* match
    score_fund = False
    def recursive(index, index2, score)
        if score_fund is True:
            return
        if score + chances < best_so_far:
            return
        if score == best_score_possible:
           score_fund = True
        # rest of code and other calls
```

This is not the real code, but it is what i'm trying to do, any ideas?
Thank you

real(not full) code:

```
def best_helper(dna_1, dna_2, index_1, index_2, score):
    best_future = score + calculate_best_future(index_1, index_2)
    if best_future < worst_score_possible:# or best_future < best_so_far:
        return worst_score_possible, dna_1, dna_2

    #returns when done and complete rest with dash
    if index_1 == len(first_dna) and index_2 == len(second_dna):
        if len(dna_1) > len(dna_2):
            dna_2 += '-' * (len(dna_1) - len(dna_2))
            score += dash * (len(dna_1) - len(dna_2))
        elif len(dna_2) > len(dna_1):
            dna_1 += '-' * (len(dna_2) - len(dna_1))
            score += dash * (len(dna_2) - len(dna_1))
        if score == best_score_possible:
            strand_found = True
        if score > best_so_far:
            best_so_far = score
        return score, dna_1, dna_2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply return an additional `Boolean value` indicating whether a solution has been found.

If the value is set to `True`, just return with the same values, until the entire stack is emptied. If it `False` you should continue on checking other possible cases.

**Example:**

```
def process_tree( best_score, node=root ):

    if not node:
        return ["NaN",False]

    node_score = node.evaluate_score()
    if node_score == best_score:
        return [best_score, True]

    score_list = []
    score_list.append(node_score)
    for child in node.children:

        child_score = process_tree(best_score,child)
        if child_score[1]:
            return child_score
        else:
            score_list.append(child_score[0])

    #when no score is equal to the best score
    return [max(score_list),False]
```

P.S. (EDIT): This example is fairly non-trivial. I hope it makes things clear-**er**.

Answer (score 0):

raise an exception

```
def main_fun(str1,str2)
    best_so_far = None
    best_score_possible = len(str)* match
    score_fund = False
    def recursive(index, index2, score)
        if score_fund is True:
            return
        if score + chances < best_so_far:
            return
        if score == best_score_possible:
           raise Exception("Best Possible Score Found!")
    try:
       recursive(0,1,0)
    except Exception as msg:
       if str(msg) == "Best Possible Score Found!":
             print "WIN!!!"
       else:
           raise
```

Comment: The problem is that i cant change or read vars from outer function, its said "unresolved refernce best so far

Comment: pyCharm says i cant :-(

Comment: you could make it a class and use instance variables ... that works in my tests or you could make the variables globals ... in your example I dont see the recursive call ...